# ReactRouter: Add types to NavLink isActive() function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm currently working on a React project using TypeScript and [ReactRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start). In some place I use the [NavLink](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) hook like this:

```js
const {itemPath} = props  // itemPath is a string

return (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <NavLink 
            to="/"
            isActive={(match: any, location: any): boolean => {
              if (!match) {
                return false;
              }
             
             if (location.pathname === itemPath) return true;

             return false;
          >
            Home
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        ...
```

As you can see, in the `isActive` function I just return `true` if the actual path (`location.pathname`) is equal too `itemPath` that come from the props.

Problem here is that I use the `any` type for both arguments of the `isActive` callback: `match` and `location`. So I decide to look into assigning them the right type but the documentation says to use this type definition that use generics:

```js
isActive?<Params>(match: match<Params>, location: Location<History<HistoryLocationState = History.PoorMansUnknown>.PoorMansUnknown>): boolean
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to type my arguments at all. Has anyone any ideas?

Comment: That's huge! Try this, `match<any | null>` can be `any` or `null`. And `location: object`

Comment: @MwamiTovi Thanks for the effort but there still an `any` in your answer and also a type `object`. Both of them are not a good practice for a well typed TypeScript app

Comment: Yes, that's true indeed. So if you want to use the `generic types`, then you might want to import those `types` from `react-router`.

Comment: @MwamiTovi Yeah sure but then I don't know how to make it correct using the generic type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `useHistory` or `useLocation`hook.

```
const {itemPath} = props  // itemPath is a string

const location = useLocation()
// or const { location } = useHistory()


return (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <NavLink 
            to="/"
            isActive={() => itemPath === location.pathname}
          >
            Home
          </NavLink>
        </li>
// ... rest
```

If you want to type the arguments, the current definition is:

```
isActive?<Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string }>(
    match: match<Params>,
    location: H.Location<S>,
): boolean;
```

I believe that typescript can correctly infer the arguments' types if you omit them. So something like this would be enough:

```
isActive={(match, location) => {
    if (!match) {
        return false
    }

    if (location.pathname === itemPath) return true

    return false
}}
```

Source: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/uselocation

Comment: Using `useLocation ()` with the arrow function works! Thanks a lot for the tip ;) Mmmh the idea about omitted the type is not a good practice because most of the projects uses code linter like `tslint` which forces to don't use implicit `any` type

Comment: Inferred types are actual types and such linters should expect this because it is a TypeScript feature. Refer to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html for more details

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';
import {withRouter} 'react-router-dom';

    const YourComponent=({history})=>(
      <Navbar>
          <NavLink 
            to="/"
            isActive={'/'===history.location.pathname}
          >
            Home
          </NavLink>
        <NavLink 
            to="/categories"
            isActive={'categories'=== history.location.pathname}
          >
            Categories
          </NavLink>
      </Navbar>
);

export default withRouter(YourComponent)
```

Comment: What's about my code structure and the fact that I don't use `history`?

Comment: This worked for me. The only thing I had to do differently was add a callback fnc to the isActive since it would not accept a boolean as a value anymore. `isActive={() => '/' === history.location.path}`

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
    
let to = "/linkroute/route"
const location = useLocation();
// pathname = "/help/linkroute/route/something"
const isActive = location.pathname.match(to);
// isActive => True
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)